# I have items arranged in a circle. How can I rotate the whole thing while keeping the inside elements upright?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sass

Im using code based off of this demo (https://codepen.io/KittyGiraudel/pen/vEJXGm) in order to arrange a few items in a circle. I want create an animation to rotate the circle however keep the elements inside upright as it rotates.

So I thought I could use simple jQuery to do a css "transform: rotate()" and then use the same thing with a negative rotation on the elements inside, however because of the way the demo is set up, the inner elements are moved to the center of the whole circle when rotated.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.box').animate(
    { deg: 72 },
    {
      duration: 1200,
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).css({ transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)' });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Alternatively, is there a way to use jQuery to change the value of the "$rot" variable? I sass variables can't be accessed by js but maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: You could try rotating the inner elements by the same amount in the opposite direction (by using `-now`)

Answer (score 0):

Since JS is not blocking, I would suggest to simply rotate your inner elements in the opposite direction of your main rotation. It would look something like this:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.box').animate(
    { deg: 72 },
    {
      duration: 1200,
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).css({ transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)' });
      }
    }
  );
  $('.box .inner').animate(
    { deg: -72 },
    {
      duration: 1200,
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).css({ transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)' });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Using the codepen you submitted, I modified it a bit for you to see what would be the actual result.

https://codepen.io/Dvermette018/pen/podGmXR

Dave

Comment: Dave, thanks for the help, but i'm  still encountering the problem of the inner circles moving to to center when rotating initiates. Here is an updated codepen showing the issue, i'm not too sure whats causing it. https://codepen.io/ericlauterbach/pen/KKyEGWO

Comment: Hi @EricMM, I am unsure what the reason behind is, but it is not possible to animate the li. Target a span inside instead. Here is a quick solution from forking your codepen.
https://codepen.io/Dvermette018/pen/vYWMreW